# Creating a Drop Down with ng-options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parse-platform

I want to create a drop down using ng-options in my html. I've seen several references on the matter and given the differences in data structure, variables etc. I do not understand how to transfer the information from my Parse backend to the drop down in the html front end.

Here is an snippet of the html I'm running:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="category in allCategories.primary">
    <select ng-model="category.primary" ng-options="bizCategories.primary for bizCategories in allCategories"></select>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript that goes with it:

```
var Categories = Parse.Object.extend("bizCategories");


   var categories = new Categories();

    $scope.primarySelect = function() {
        var primary = new Parse.Query(Categories);
        primary.find({
            success:function(list){
                $scope.allCategories = list;
                }
            })
        }
```

The Parse database has a collection called bizCategories with a column called primary which has a one word string in each row.

Here is a picture of primary in the bizCategories collection:
[image]

Comment: what does allCategories contain?

Comment: allCategories contains the search results which contains (I think - I'm a newbie and allCategories is my first query ever) an array of objects that are one word strings from the primary column of the bizCategories collection.

Comment: Added. Primary stretches on for quite away and has other entries. Ultimately I'll need to add _unique as a filter to the query (don't know how to do that yet) to get the right info in the box but for now, I just want to get ng-options working.

Comment: how can you use ng-repeat and ng-options together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Parse objects require you to use the `get('columnName')` function to read values, whereas Angular works best with plain objects.

What I've done is map my Parse objects to simple objects using the Underscore library as follows:

```
$scope.primarySelect = function() {
    var primary = new Parse.Query(Categories);
    primary.find({
        success:function(list){
            $scope.allCategories = _(list).map(function(item) {
                return {
                    // not sure if you need the ID, remove this line if you don't
                    id: item.id,
                    primary: item.get('primary'),
                    // add any other properties you need here
                };
            });
        }
    });
}
```

You could also tell Underscore to reduce it to a unique list if needed (which you would have to do after mapping).

Oh also you should set ng-model to something in your scope you want to hold the selected object (e.g. ng-model="selectedPrimary"). If instead you just want the selected text let me know and I'll give you a sample of how that would look.

Comment: Thanks for sending this over. It's good to see how underscore is used. I know I'll have to use it in the near future. I tried your code but it didn't work and unlike the first time, I gave it some time as I'm up and fresh. I fooled around with it a bit but no luck there. I tried console.log(list) to see what I get but that didn't work either. 

Also, what changes would I make in the html if I could get this to work?

Comment: I fiddled with it and the underscore was implemented wrong I think: 

$scope.primarySelect = function() {
            var primary = new Parse.Query(Categories);
            primary.find({
                success:function(list){
                    $scope.allCategories = _.map(list, function(item){
                        return{primary: primary.get('primary')}
                    })
                    console.log($scope.allCategories);
                    }
                })
            }

Comment: Great, took a long path to understanding (sort of) but I have it working as it's supposed to. Thanks!

Comment: Underscore has 2 modes of working, `_(list).map(function(item) {..})` and `_.map(list, function(item) {..})`. They are equivalent, I just like the first way better. The 2nd way is easier while you are still learning everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <select ng-model="bizCategories.primary" ng-options="bizCategories.primary for bizCategories in allCategories"></select>
</div>
```

Try out this. If doesn't work let me know.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ym0d9qaL/
```

Comment: No dice on that one. It did shorten the size of the drop down but that's not my main worry at this time.

Comment: Please check fiddler link. its working for me. I dont understand which type of data you get into allCategories. There should be some valid json data in allCategories...

Comment: I think it just took some time to load but the formatting is off so I'll need to take another look in the morning. Thanks a million!

Comment: Ok, I had to tinker with the html a bit to view the results; earlier I knew it was returning a result in the JS console but only now was I able to see that it is returning the whole collection whereas I only want an array of the string value in the primary column of the bizCategories collection.